# Issue with a GUI in Python

Tags: python

I am working on a GUI where I have to calculate miles per gallon of a car.  I keep getting a syntax error but I am not sure what I am doing wrong here is the code I have: I have edited it to reflect some corrections

```
class GasMileage:
 def__init__(self)
        #Create main window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        #Create 4 frames
        self.gallons_frame = tkinter.frame(self.main_windown)
        self.miles_frame = tkinter.frame(self.main_windown)
        self.button_frame = tkinter.frame(self.main_windown)
        self.mpg_frame = tkinter.frame(self.main_window)

        #Create and pack widgets Gallons and Miles

        self.gallons_label = tkinter.Label(self.gallons_frame, \
                                           text "Enter # of Gallons Used")
        self.gallons_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.gallons_frame, \
                                           width = 10)

        self.miles_label.pack(side='left')
        self.miles_entry.pack(side='left')

        self.miles_label = tkinter.Label(self.miles_frame, \
                                           text="Enter miles traveled")
        self.miles_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.miles_frame, \
                                           width = 10)

        self.miles_label.pack(side='left')
        self.miles_entry.pack(side='left')

        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.mpg_frame, \
                                          text='MPG=')
        self.mpg = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.mpg_label = tkinter.Label(self.mpg_frame, \
                                       textvariable=self.mpg)
        self.result_label.pack (side='left')
        self.mpg_label.pack(side='left')

        #Create and pack button Widgets

        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, \
                                          text='Calculate MPG', \
                                          command=self.calc_gallons)

        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, \
                                          text='Exit', \
                                          command=self.main_window.destroy)
        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        #Pack the frames

        self.gallons_frame.pack()
        self.miles_frame.pack()
        self.buttons_frame.pack()
        self.mpg_frame.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

        #Calculate Miles per Gallon

        def calc_gallons(self):

            self.gallons = float(self.gallons_entry.get())
            self.miles = float(self.miles_entry.get())

            #Calculate Miles per Gallon

            self.mpg = self.miles / self.gallons

        gas_miles = GasMileage()
```

Comment: Just qickly: `def__init__(self)` should be `def __init__(self):`

Comment: the actual error would be handy to know

Comment: The only thing it is saying is invalid syntax that is the only error I am getting

Comment: there has to be a traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code, but its full of mistakes and inconsistencies. Now at least it compiles and executes:

```
import tkinter



class GasMileage:

    def __init__(self):
        #Create main window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        #Create 4 frames
        self.gallons_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.miles_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.mpg_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #Create and pack widgets Gallons and Miles

        self.gallons_label = tkinter.Label(self.gallons_frame, 
                                           text = "Enter # of Gallons Used")
        self.gallons_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.gallons_frame, 
                                           width = 10)


        self.gallons_label.pack(side='left')
        self.gallons_entry.pack(side='left')                



        self.miles_label = tkinter.Label(self.miles_frame,
                                           text = "Enter miles traveled")
        self.miles_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.miles_frame, 
                                           width = 10)

        self.miles_label.pack(side='left')
        self.miles_entry.pack(side='left')        


        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.mpg_frame,  text='MPG=')
        self.mpg = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.mpg_label = tkinter.Label(self.mpg_frame, 
                                       textvariable=self.mpg)
        self.result_label.pack (side='left')
        self.mpg_label.pack(side = 'left')

        #Create and pack button Widgets

        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, 
                                          text='Calculate MPG', 
                                          command=self.calc_gallons)

        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, 
                                          text='Exit',
                                          command=self.main_window.destroy)
        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        #Pack the frames

        self.gallons_frame.pack()
        self.miles_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()
        self.mpg_frame.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

    #Calculate Miles per Gallon


![enter image description here][1]

    def calc_gallons(self):

        self.gallons = float(self.gallons_entry.get())
        self.miles = float(self.miles_entry.get())

        print(self.gallons, self.miles)

        #Calculate Miles per Gallon

        self.mpg = self.miles / self.gallons
        self.result_label['text'] = "'MPG = '{:0.2f}".format(self.mpg)

gas_miles = GasMileage()
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why it was downvoted? the answer solves all the syntax erross of OP. And screenshot is the proof of this.

Comment: Im not sure, but thanks for your help